# 'dpkg-reconfigure ntp' and no configuration taking place

Tags: debian, time, ntp

I've got a clock skew on an older Core2 duo laptop used for testing. Its causing make to complain about sources files being dated in the future after an `scp`. According to the [Debian NTP wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/NTP) under Install and Configure:

```
dpkg-reconfigure ntp
```

It produces the following, with no configuration choices:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure ntp
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
```

I found `/etc/default/ntp`, but there's not much to it:

```
$ cat /etc/default/ntp
NTPD_OPTS='-g'
```

How do I set the time servers and the update interval?

---

```
$ ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
\*static-96-244-9 192.168.10.254   2 u   39   64   17    8.012    2.418   0.676
 srcf-ntp.stanfo 171.64.7.67      2 u   41   64   17   71.084    0.577   0.722
 soft-sea-01.ser 209.51.161.238   2 u   40   64   17   68.163    4.503   0.953
 bindcat.fhsu.ed 132.163.4.103    2 u   35   64   17   63.176    2.035   0.548
```

Answer (score 0):

/etc/defaults/ntp only configures the lanch enviroment of the daemon

the servers are set in `/etc/ntp.conf`

Install ntp-doc for the man pages for that file and ntpd

Comment: Thanks. How do I set the time servers and the update interval?